# Когда слова ВЫ или ТЫ — обращение?

Tags: синтаксис

Объясните, пожалуйста, как обособить обращение от подлежащего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что говорится в [полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина (М., 2006 и др.):](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129)

*Личные местоимения **ты** и **вы** обычно не выступают в роли обращений: они выполняют функцию подлежащего, если при них имеются глаголы-сказуемые.*

*Если вы, читатель, любите осень, то знаете, что осенью вода в реках приобретает от холода яркий синий цвет* (Пауст.).
Местоимение **вы** — подлежащее (*вы любите*), а **читатель** — пояснительный член предложения (*вы*, т. е. *читатель*).

Местоимения **ты, вы** могут выполнять функцию обращения в следующих случаях:

а) при наличии определительных конструкций — обособленных определений или определительных придаточных частей предложения.

**Вы, третья с краю, с копной на лбу, я вас не знаю. Я вас — люблю** (Возн.);
**Вы, чьи широкие шинели напоминали паруса, чьи шпоры весело звенели и голоса, и чьи глаза, как бриллианты, на сердце оставляли след, — очаровательные франты минувших лет** (Цвет.).

***Такие*** местоимения не являются подлежащими, при них нет глаголов-сказуемых.

б) при самостоятельном употреблении, обычно с междометиями **эй, ну, эх, цыц** и др. (в разговорной речи):
**— Цыц, ты! Она тебе больше не слуга** (М. Г.);
**— Эй, ты! Ответь мне** (Шукш.);
**— Ну, ты! Не перечь мне!**

в) в сложных обращениях:
**Милый друг ты мой, не стыдись...** (Фадеев);
**Манюшка, милая ты моя...** (Шукшин).

Comment: Извините, но мне кажется, что _Полный академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина_ нужно писать с большой буквы. Ведь это название книги. http://www.old-rozental.ru/

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, думаю, полный академический справочник можно расматривать и как  имя  нарицательное. Посмотрите ответы Грамоты.ру. Там везде строчная.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjUq-OX06HWAhUJbhQKHb91CfcQFgg2MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgramota.ru%2Flenta%2Fnews%2F8_2028&usg=AFQjCNE0hX_4gqQo8Li_BgbcEf7OCqlNkA